# Redux, timing for rendering information

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, timing

I'm trying to use information from my redux store in a component and I need to better understand the timing of when information is received. I have the following navigation component with a mapStateToProps call and I'd like to have the profile pic link load into the header... like Facebook or many sites that have a user signed in.

```
class Navigation extends Component {

// IF WE HAVE A USER PROFILE, DYNAMICALLY DEFINE THE LOGIN/PROFILE PICTURE 
    renderContent() {
        switch (this.props.auth.data) {
            case null:
                return;
            case false || "":
                return (
                    <Button href='/auth/google'>Login</Button>
                );
            default:
                return <img src={this.props.auth.data.googleImage} alt='Profile Image' />
        }
    }

// MY NAVIGATION COMPONENT WITH A {this.renderContent()} CALL
    render() {
        console.log(this.props.auth)
        return (
            <nav id="nav">
               ... this.renderContent() ...
            </nav>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { auth: state.auth }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Navigation);
```

When the component loads, I get an error saying "Cannot read property 'googleImage' of undefined". I understand that this action is asynchronous and the page first loads with no information yet, then the browser receives the information, but i'm not sure how to overcome this issue 
Please help.

Thanks,

Comment: Hello Tyler, when are you setting the contents of your `auth` reducer?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code snipped you have above, it sounds like your intent is that this component loads sometime after the `auth` reducer has engagned. This is a reasonable requiement, but not one that is somehow enforced or intuitied by React/Redux.

When you test your page in a browser (and get the  "Cannot read property 'googleImage' of undefined" error), open your Chrome developer tools and take a look at your Redux store. You will find that while you have an `auth` object, it likely has no proporities.

Install and setup the Chrome extension [Redux Dev Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en) and reload your page. Open the development console and broswse to the Redux tab. You should see a list of all of the Redux actions that have been fired, along with the state changes each one produced. At the time of the error, you will probably see that either no USER_LOGGED_IN action has yet fired (or whatever your action is called), or that it did fire, but did not produce a state change that filled in the auth tools.

If the logic action is being dispatched after your page with this component loads, theny ou will need to change how your app os organized if you really need to guarantee that the login information is present when this component loads.

Alternatively, you can restructure your component to display an alternate icon or element when no auth information is present. Then, once the dispatch for the login occurs (and the reducer fills in the auth data) your component will automatically get updated and re-rendered.